# How to get the position of the touch when in UITableView Drag&Drop

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm implementing drag&drop in a UITableView, the problem is how to get the position of the touch?
So I can tell the cell is dropped at the area 1,2,3,4 or 5.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can override touchesBegan(:with:) and have an x and y variable to keep track of the locations, see here for documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_touches_in_your_view.